# Javascript runtime error in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a new ASP .net mvc 2 web application with that default template provided in VS 2008. I wanted to check the document.ready to see on how it fires. So in Site.Master I included the jQuery Scripts in the following way:

"

```
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.validate.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.validate.min-vsdoc.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.validate.min.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftAjax.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")%>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I load the application, I get the following javascript error:

Error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'.
Parameter name: instance
Source File: http://localhost:1108/Scripts/JQuery/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
Line: 1559

Don't know whats wrong in this? I checked if the jquery files are not downloaded, but all of them get downloaded fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including **WAY** to much stuff.

Your error is because your are including both MicrosoftAjax.debug.js and MicrosoftAjax.js. Choose one.

The *.debug.js files are same as the *.js files but in a readable format. Readable means larger file size and should only be used during development.

The *.vsdoc.js files are only for intellicense in Visual Studio and should never be included like this.